# Enter Frame Loop is updating the enemy class but enemy is not moving

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

```
    public function Goblin()
    {
        move = true;
        nTimer = 0;
        speed = 1;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd)
    }

    private function onAdd(e:Event):void 
    {
        trace("added Goblin");
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd);
    }

    public function goblinLoop() 
    {
        trace("yes");
        //trace(nTimer);

        this.x -= 4;


    }
```

This is the enemy class, and you can see I'm not using an enter frame to move it. Instead, from the main class I am...

```
    private function updatePlayer():void 
    {
        character.keyListner();
        character.movementChar();
        goblin1.goblinLoop();
        goblin2.goblinLoop();

    }
```

What I don't understand is that it traces "yes" in the output panel, but the goblin does not move, despite the function being called.

Comment: does it work if you try goblin1.x -= 4 in the updatePlayer method?

Comment: Nope, goblin1.x -=4 does not make it move, thanks for the input though

Comment: Showing us more code may help us help you.

Comment: Is the trace being called every frame?

Comment: Most likely your goblins don't get added to stage, so you're moving *wrong* goblins. They move, but they are not the goblins you are looking for. **jedi hand move** To debug this, you can do `trace("yes", this.name)` in `Goblin.goblinLoop` function, and `trace(goblin1.name,goblin2.name)` in `updatePlayer` function.

Comment: I think we need to know if you can actually see the goblins (this sounds a little like a sanity test, but I'm sure you know what I mean). If you CAN see the goblins, and you are calling the updatePlayer function just once (there's no event parameter in that function), then your goblins might actually be moving, but only once.

Comment: It's tracing "yes" every frame, therefore the goblin should update. 

But it's working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone back to enterFrame for now, I will use an update method when I have developed the skills and researched more in to enterFrames any why not to use them (multi threaded games).

Thank you for your input.

Comment: You need at least one enter frame listener anyway, if you want your game to actually do something automatically. (You can, however, use a timer, but enterframe ensures that your game is updated at constant speed, looking from game logic side.) There, you should have set of things to do, say `updateAllGoblins()`, `updatePlayer()`, `updateOtherObstacles()` etc., in these you run a for-each cycle against the approppriate array of objects calling `update()` for all of them once. This is the core of any game calling "game loop". Of course, all state changes have to be parsed in there as well.